# Remote web services are called every minute without me calling them

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, jar

I have a spring boot project. I deploy my project remotely as a jar at tomcat. The script i run on the remote server to deploy the jar :

> #!/bin/sh
>
> /usr/local/java8/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/java -jar
>   -Duser.timezone=Europe/Athens  example.jar> log.out

The whole project is working fine but sometimes web services are called automatically without me doing something or having a scheduler calling them.

For example a method in my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/heartbeat")
public ResponseEntity<String> heartbeat() {
    Log.info("heartbeat");
    return new ResponseEntity<>("success", org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

When the project is deployed remotely i can see from the logs that this method is getting called every minute, even though noone is calling it:

> 02/05/19 15:23:22.721 INFO  http-nio-8044-exec-9 TestController:238 -
>   heartbeat
>
> 02/05/19 15:24:22.133 INFO  http-nio-8044-exec-1 TestController:238 -
>   heartbeat
>
> 02/05/19 15:25:22.426 INFO  http-nio-8044-exec-8 TestController:238 -
>   heartbeat
>
> 02/05/19 15:26:22.782 INFO  http-nio-8044-exec-7 TestController:238 -
>   heartbeat
>
> 02/05/19 15:27:22.179 INFO  http-nio-8044-exec-5 TestController:238 -
>   heartbeat

In my pom and properties i cannot find something related to a scheduler. Also none of my controller methods are annotated with @Scheduled. Any ideas?

**application.properties**

```
management.context-path=/internal/manage
management.security.enabled=false
endpoints.health.id = health
endpoints.health.sensitive = true
endpoints.health.enabled = true
endpoints.info.id=info
endpoints.info.sensitive=false
endpoints.info.enabled=true
info.app.name=Test app name
info.app.description=Test project
endpoints.actuator.enabled=true
spring.application.admin.enabled=true
endpoints.hypermedia.enabled=true
management.info.git.mode=full
```

Comment: That's incredibly hard to answer. But you could start by analysing the requests. If it only happens remotely you could add some more logging that gives you an insight on the request. `RequestContext` is your friend there.

Comment: I know it's hard to answer but i had to ask because i found this impossible. It is only happening remotely so yes i will try to see what is happening with HttpServletRequest and more logs.

Comment: any idea what should i check from RequestContext?

Comment: Are you using kubernetes? or using actuator for health checks?

Comment: The constant frequency of polling suggests a load balancer testing if you're alive. If this is a cloud environment it may be there without you knowing about it. Log the caller's IP address and all request headers in your heartbeat() call and trace it back.

Comment: Ok i will check it. I have many other jars running on this server but this is the first time it is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using /internal/manage/trace.json endpoint, i found out that the web services are called by a heatlh status tool. I just didn't knew we were using this tool.

Answer (score 0):

It could a kubernetes liveliness probe, if the end-point /heartbeat is configured as a liveliness probe, kubernetes polls the end-point at every configured time interval to check if the service is alive. In your case, it is one min.

If you are not in a kubernetes environment, the end-point may be invoked by a monitoring system to check the service health.

Comment: I edit my question and i included my application.properties. I am not using kubernetes enviroment and the end-point is not known to any monitoring system to be invoked.